# Jquery/php selectbox show/hide div

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

What I want here is to show or hide divs according to the text selected in options not the value its easy when you don't have php...

How can I do that in jquery that if selected text in my case selected text is

```
<?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
```

is equal to some text then show this div else show other div.

```
<select id="opt" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]">
            <option value="0"><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
            <?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>
            <?php } ?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try outputting the value you want to match in an inline js block, or in a hidden input

PHP CODE:

```
<input id="matchvalue" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>" />
```

jQuery:

```
  var matchvalue = $('#matchvalue').val();
  $('#opt').change(function(){
    if( $(this).find('option:selected').text() == matchvalue){
       //DO WHATEVER
    }else{
      //NO MATCH
    }
  });
```

That could work, or you could output the "var matchvalue" into a js block somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
    jQuery( '#opt' ).change( function(){
        if( jQuery( this ).find( ':selected' ).text() == theValue ){
          jQuery( '#mypositiveelement' ).show();
          jQuery( '#mynegativeelement' ).hide(); //or whatever
        }else{
          jQuery( '#mypositiveelement' ).hide();
          jQuery( '#mynegativeelement' ).show(); //or whatever
        }
    } );
} );
```

Then in your HTML you could add an inline script like

```html
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    var theValue = "<?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>";
//]]></script>
```